# How to backup data from same SQL Server database on different locations and restored to one using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

We have 4 branches on different locations, as a security we need to backup data from these locations and restored it in main branch SQL Server. What is the best practise for doing it? Can I do it using C#?

Now I'm planning to make a XML of daily data, encrypt it, send these file to the main branch through Google Drive (using api) and there convert those XML files into data table, back it up (but I don't think it is a good idea)

Main branch doesn't have any static IP.

Comment: Can you use .bak file? If yes, then you can do it by c# using SMO.

Comment: So you want to have 4x separate database on the serve rat the main branch? Are the branches connected via a VPN?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are couple of solutions for such requirement. Including replication, log shipping, backup-restore and so on.  Take a look at topics in [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if the question is more suitable for that site.